# How can I fix the default bash syntax highlighter?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm having some issue with the default "Dr. Chip" `sh.vim` highlighter. Specifically, it's failing to recognise the comment character `#` after a `touch` command. e.g.

```
touch foo # it's here
```

It doesn't see the `#`, and hence the `'` is parsed, marking all lines after this a "quoted string".

[image: Syntax failing]

In @akshay's case, highlighting [works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwQTt.jpg) as expected. I'm using the following:

- Arch Linux
- Vim 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Apr 29 2016 11:28:12); Included patches: 1-1797
- sh.vim version 147, but I also tried version 151

I've also tested without plugins or vimrc activated (`vim -u NONE /tmp/test.sh`), but this also fails.

In this case, `:scriptnames` produces the following:

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftdetect/csv.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftdetect/r.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/sh.vim
```

And `:set filetype?` shows `filetype=sh`.

Comment: Are you sure? It seems to be working fine for me, with your example using the default sh.vim syntax highlighter. What is your Vim version?

Comment: @akshay Yes I'm sure, but TBH I was a it surprised that it would fail on a relatively common usage case. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/3onPc9e.png). I'm using `Vim 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Apr 29 2016 11:28:12); Included patches: 1-1797` on Arch Linux. I'm using `sh.vim` version 147, but I tried the very latest and still have this problem.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work fine for me, although I am using version 151: Here's a [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/WiaCw6g.png) from my end.

Comment: @akshay Yes, version 151 was the one I tested too (and also failed). Good to know that it can work though. I wonder why that could be. Preferably I'd just like to get the default working, so I'll edit the question. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Use the vim_use mailing list to contact the maintainer of that script. He is usually pretty reactive.

Comment: Thanks @romainl. Good idea. (I just emailed him instead, so I don't have to subscribe to a mailing list.)

Comment: Just to confirm, was the detected filetype `sh`? What's the output of `scriptnames`, after you open that file?

Comment: @muru I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Charles E Campbell (aka Dr Chip), the maintainer of default `sh.vim` highlighter. He responded very quickly with a new [version 152](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#SYNTAX_SH) that fixes this problem for me. I'm still not sure why this problem only affected me and not @akshay though.

[image: fixes syntax]